# Win32Exception - Class already exists

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I am getting Win32Exception - "Class already exists" in production code. Same code works without a problem in my demo project. What can be a problem?

```
Private Class MyClientWindow
    Inherits NativeWindow

    Public Sub New(ByVal parent As Form)

        Dim cp As CreateParams = New CreateParams()

        ' Fill in the CreateParams details.
        cp.Caption = "Parent Static Window"
        cp.ClassName = "Static"

        ' Set the position on the form
        cp.X = 0
        cp.Y = 0
        cp.Height = 0
        cp.Width = 0

        ' Specify the form as the parent.
        cp.Parent = parent.Handle

        ' Create as a child of the specified parent
        cp.Style = WS_CHILD Or WS_VISIBLE

        ' Create the actual window 
        Me.CreateHandle(cp)
    End Sub

End Class

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled by user code. 
ErrorCode=-2147467259,     
Message=Class already exists, 
NativeErrorCode=1410, 
StackTrace:
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WindowClass.RegisterClass()
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WindowClass.Create(String className, Int32 classStyle)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
```

Comment: What happens if you change the Classname?

Comment: Yes, capitalizing classname make it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing class name from "Static" to "STATIC" seams to work. I have found remarks on that in [CreateParams.ClassName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.createparams.classname.aspx):

> to derive from the standard Button control, set this ClassName property to
>   "BUTTON"